# Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request ( AWS API GATEWAY , Post request )

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

**Background**: I have a API that takes 3 minutes to process, I am giving input as a PDF (Body-->form-data in postman) and sending data in POST request.

[image]

Which works fine locally, but I want to host this on AWS.

Workflow:
API gateway-->SQS-->lambda

**Tried so far:**

On API Gateway I have selected "REST API" and "Integration request" I have selected the following parameters:

[image]

I Have clicked on "test" I get this error:

```
Response body
{"message": "Unsupported Media Type"}
Response headers
{
"x-amzn-ErrorType": "BadRequestException"
}
```

**Test Log Error**:

```
Execution log for request b50b96fa-bdb7-42ef-8187-3480feb4bc1c
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Starting execution for request: b50b96fa-bdb7-42ef-8187-3480feb4bc1c
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /parse_pdf
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Method request path: {}
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Method request query string: {}
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Method request headers: {}
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Method request body before transformations:
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Execution failed: null
Tue Feb 13 21:41:25 UTC 2024 : Method completed with status: 415\`
```

**Cloud watch logs error:**

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
(d8c102ab-7f40-47f4-b629-d8546bf56594) Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request

2024-02-13T15:31:54.181-06:00   (d8c102ab-7f40-47f4-b629-d8546bf56594) Method completed with status: 500\](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

Expecting: To send message to SQS which has this request and PDF (post request)